# Functional digits reversion

Tags: f#

In C, I would solve the problem with a loop. To represent the idea, something like:

```
void foo(int x){
    while(x > 0){
        printf("%d", x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
}
```

With F#, I am unable to make the function return the single values. I tried:

```
let reverse = 
    let aux =
        fun x -> 
            x % 10
    let rec aux2 =
        fun x -> 
            if x = 0 then 0
            else aux2(aux(x / 10))
    aux2 n
```

but it returns always the base case `0`.

I cannot get my mind beyond this approach, where the recursion results are maintained with an operation, and cannot be reported  (according to may comprehension) individually:

```
let reverse2 =
    let rec aux =
        fun x -> 
            if x = 0 then 0
            else (x % 10) + aux (x / 10)     // The operation  returning the result
    aux n
```

This is a simple exercise I am doing in order to "functionalize" my mind. Hence, I am looking for an approach to this problem not involving library functions.

Comment: You're overusing the `fun` keyword and it makes your code hard to read. You can write `let rec aux x = ...` instead of `let rec aux = fun x -> ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A for loop that changes the value of mutable variables can be rewritten as a recursive function. You can think of the mutable variables as implicit parameters to the function. So if we have a mutable variable `x`, we need to instead pass the new state of `x` explicitly as a function parameter. The closest equivalent to your C function as a recursive F# function is this:

```
let rec foo x =
    if x > 0 then
        printf "%d" (x % 10)
        foo (x / 10)
```

This in itself isn't particularly functional because it returns `unit` and only has side effects. You can collect the result of each loop using another parameter. This is often called an accumulator:

```
let foo x =
    let rec loop x acc =
        if x > 0 then
            loop (x / 10) (x % 10 :: acc)
        else acc

    loop x [] |> List.rev

foo 100  // [0; 0; 1]
```

I made an inner `loop` function that is actually the recursive one. The outer `foo` function starts off the inner loop with `[]` as the accumulator. Items are added to the start of the list during each iteration and the accumulator list is reversed at the end.

You can use another type as the accumulator, e.g. a string, and append to the string instead of adding items to the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make a little of practice on it.

Comment: The first approach you proposed returns a type unit. Is it correct?

Comment: The first function is just replicating the C function that you wrote in your question, which returns void, which is effectively the same as unit. I'm not really proposing it :)